# Is check that notification channel is already created needed?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, push-notification, android-notifications

Do we need to check before creating notification channel that it isn't already created?

```
 private fun createChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        // todo: add here check if channel is already created
        val defaultChannel = NotificationChannel(MEDIA_UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, MEDIA_UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
        defaultChannel.description = MEDIA_UPLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_DESC
        defaultChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(defaultChannel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, you don't really have to check that. If a channel with the same ID exists then Android doesn't create another.

As per docs

> Creating an existing notification channel with its original values performs no operation, so it's safe to call this code when starting an app.

More info at https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannel

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in the documentation.

> If creating a NotificationChannel with the same original values there won't be any operation. So, it's safe to call the code.

Please checkout documentation for more details - https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels#CreateChannel

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java) as NotificationManager
            if(notificationManager.getNotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID") == null) {
                val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel("CHANNEL_ID", "CHANNEL_NAME", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT)
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
            }
        }
```

As other mentioned above there's no need to check for existence unless you are doing something particular.